# I need help create a TSQL function

Tags: t-sql

I need a function created (EscapeAmpersand). The function should take 1 varchar(255) parameter. It should return a varchar(255) parameter. The purpose of the function is to take the input, replace `‘&’` with `‘&amp;’` and return the results.

Examples:

Input: `‘my dog & me’` return: `‘my dog &amp; me’`

Input: `‘my dog and me’` return: `‘my dog and me’`

Comment: That's what `REPLACE()` is for ... use or wrap that.

Comment: This is the kind of thing better handled by the presentation layer. There are built in functions you can use in most if not all web related programming languages and environments that will do it better.

Comment: Was this homework? If so, note that you'd not learn much if you just get people to write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scalar-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fReplaceAmpersand (@InputString VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS  
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(@InputString, '&', '&amp;')
END
GO
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.fReplaceAmpersand(MyText)
FROM MyTable
```

From a performance standpoint, if your tables are very large you'll be better off using a table-valued function and OUTER APPLY:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fReplaceAmpersand (@InputString VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS  
    RETURN 
    SELECT REPLACE(@InputString, '&', '&amp;') AS OutputString
GO
--  ----------------------------------------------------
SELECT a.OutputString
FROM MyTable m
    OUTER APPLY dbo.fReplaceAmpersand(m.MyText) a
```

Non-procedural table-valued functions can operate several times faster than scalar-valued ones.

Comment: NP, glad to help. Note that the returned value is larger because for every replace operation you're making the string four characters longer by adding "amp;". Technically, it should return varchar(1275) in case they pass in 255 ampersands, but this seemed practical. You could change it to LEFT(REPLACE..., 1000) if you're paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE( input,'&','&'||'amp')
```