# What does two return statements inside an SQL function mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What code path is actually being returned from this a Scalar function that returns a decimal:

```
DECLARE @SafetyStockUnitsCalcNew decimal(14,2)  
   RETURN( SELECT STDEV(
     .
     .
     --  Calculating code here. 

     )

-- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @SafetyStockUnitsCalcNew 
END
```

So what gets returned?

Is it the first return scaler statement or the second scaler one?

---

Also, once `@SafetyStockUnitsCalcNew` is declared it is never used until it is returned. Where is it set?

The code inside `STDEV` does not reference `@SafetyStockUnitsCalcNew` at all.

Comment: the second return should never execute, since the first one will always trigger.

Comment: Are you sure it's working correctly as is?

Comment: Yes, it's working it returns a value.

Comment: I would say that the first return is executed and returns whatever the select produces, and the second return is never reached. Functions should only allow one return statement.

Comment: It's almost certainly left over from someone rewriting the proc. It was probably [DECLARE @] --> [SELECT @ = ...] --> [RETURN @]. In fact, if you can refactor it into a non-procedural table-valued function, it may return up to 10x faster (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576958/i-need-help-create-a-tsql-function).

Answer (score 6):

A function can have as many `RETURN` statements as you want.

E.g. Below there are three.

When the flow of control encounters a `return` statement then execution of the function stops and the value is returned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Foo(@x int)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
IF @x = 1
   RETURN 10;
ELSE
   RETURN 18;

RETURN 1/0;
END
```

SQL Server does not do anything like the same level of analysis as happens in C# to detect that all code paths return a value and warn you of unreachable code. It just insists that the last statement must be a `return`.

In the above example the third `RETURN` statement can never be reached but nonetheless without it you would see an error "The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.".

In your example the second `RETURN` statement can never be reached and it is not required for the "last statement" rule either so it is useless. Perhaps originally the `SELECT` assigned the result to the variable and then the person coding it realised that they could just return the `SELECT` result directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go on to a test server, create the function and comment out that second RETURN and see what happens.  I'm 99% sure that it is never executing.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer in my opinion

Comment: you are right it doesn't execute. Hmmm  I wonder what the purpose of putting that second return statement in there? It must be a bug